# Converting HTML pages with MathML equations to Word document

Tags: html, msword

My goal is to convert this document (https://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/252/lorentztrans.html) which contains math into word document with well formatted equations.

Why only Microsoft Word you ask? I am teaching myself physics from this lecture notes. I make all my notes in onenote (on my Ipad with handwritten equations and hand-drawn diagrams using ipencil). The thing is, OneNote has same equation system as the Microsoft Word. If its converted into Word, then it is converted into OneNote.

I have tried all possibilities I could by Googling. I tried the following methods without success.

Method 1: Copy pasting MathML into MS Word. It is working for some simple equations, I found elsewhere. But strangely, it isn't working for any equations from this website. I think there is something strange about MathML of this website.

Method 2: Converting from HTML to docx using pandoc. I saved the html (only) of this page. Then used `pandoc -s input.html -o output.docx`. It skipped all the equations.

Method 3: Copypasting directly into MS Word and Apache OpenOffice Write.

I don't mind converting first into intermediate format and then converting it into Word.

Comment: The time you spend looking for an automatic solution could be used doing it manually.   However this question doesn't seem to be about TeX, Latex and friends, so is not on topic for this site.

Comment: converting from mathml to word does not involve tex at all so it is clearly off topic here, sorry.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question does not involve TeX

Comment: @JamesK: I am looking for an automatic solution because I need to do it for hundreds of pages. The author has written all his lecture notes in this format.